# Locking litecoin wallet with JSON-RPC

Tags: wallet, litecoin, api, json-rpc, encryption

There is this very [helpful post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1762/how-to-call-json-rpc-sendtoaddress-when-the-wallet-is-encrypted) detailing how to lock and unlock your bitcoin wallet using `walletlock` and `walletpassphrase` api calls. Unfortunately the [litecoin api](https://litecoin.info/Litecoin_API) does not boast these features.

I was wondering if there is a similar strategy in place for securing a litecoin wallet perhaps using the `lockunspent` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Litecoin-Qt/litecoind v0.8.5.2 and probably several v0.8 releases before do support these api calls.

The --help doesn't seem to have any entries on these commands but this is true of Bitcoin-Qt/bitcoind as well so if you want to submit a bug report or code it and submit a pull request, please do so at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.